# How to pass a set of variables to a class

Tags: php, class, oop

This may be a bit of an XY questions, so I'm going to explain what I'm trying to do first. I'm attempting to create a single php file to handle all of my page refresh AJAX calls. That means I want to be able to send it a class name, plus a list of the variables that the class constructor takes, and for it to then create the class.

I can create the class fine. `$class = new $className();` works just fine for creating the class. The problem is passing in the default variables. Most of the variables are objects containing other classes, so I can't just include this once the class is created, I need to pass them as the class is created.

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
$varStr = '';
$s = '';
foreach($vars as $var) {
    switch($var['type']) {
        case 'object':
            $varStr .= $s . '$' . $var['value'];
            break;
        case 'variable':
            $varStr .= $s . $var['value'];
    }
    $s = ',';
}
$class = new $className(echo $varStr);
```

Now obviously echo $varStr isn't going to work there, but I have no idea what will. Is there anything I can do that will output the variables from my array into the class constructor like that? Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Is there a better way?

Whilst I understand I could just pass the whole array to the class constructor, this would complicate the main part of the program, and I would rather just ditch the idea of a single page for AJAX refresh than go down that route.

Comment: You may want to read about [`Reflection::newInstanceArgs`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php)

Comment: Do you need to pass objects to the constructor, or could you pass the results of method calls or data members?  I ask because making classes rely on the workings of other classes couples them together pretty tightly and can result in some extra maintenance.

Comment: Why would passing an array to the constructor complicate things? (more than what you're doing)

Comment: @SurrealDreams I will be mostly passing objects to the constructor.

Comment: @Ben It would require a large amount of rewriting, which I simply don't have the time for.

Comment: @Styphon Hard to tell without seeing the rest of your code, but an array of objects shouldn't take many more lines of codes to parse than your sample code above.

Comment: @Ben there are a lot of classes that would need to be rewritten to accommodate that and I'm on a tight deadline.

Comment: Can't help much further without seeing more code..

Comment: @Ben what code would you like to see? I have provided example code above, but other than a couple of lines fetching the variables from POST and then creating the class, there isn't any code.

Comment: Posted answer, *maaayybe* that's what you mean..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a wild guess at what you're trying to do but maybe this is what you're after:

```
// Generate constructor args

$args = array();
foreach($vars as $var) {
    switch($var['type']) {
        $value = $var['value'];
        case 'object':
            args[] = ${$value};     // evaluate, I think that's what you want?
            break;
        case 'variable':
            args[] = $value;        // use as is
            break;
    }

}

// Instanciate class with args
$class = new ReflectionClass($className);
$obj = $class->newInstanceArgs($args);
```

For this to work, it would require $vars to enumerates args in the correct order expected by each class constructor.

Comment: I got to this conclusion myself and as I just checked back to accept the other answer I saw this. This is exactly what I came to. I struggled to get my head around the ReflectionClass at first, but wow, that's some clever stuff PHP can do.

Comment: @deceze should probably get the credit for the ReflectionClass bit.. but he's got enough rep points :P

Answer (score 7):

So basically you're trying to pass a variable number of arguments to a constructor? In a regular function, you could do something like:

```
function foo() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    ...
}

call_user_func_array('foo', array('bar', 'baz'));
```

This won't work for constructors, since the calling mechanism is different. You could do:

```
class Foo {

    public function __construct() {
        $args = func_get_args();
        ...
    }

}

$class = new ReflectionClass('Foo');
$obj = $class->newInstanceArgs(array('bar', 'baz'));
```

But really, what you should be doing is this:

```
class Foo {

    public function __construct(array $args) {
        ...
    }

}

$obj = new Foo(array('bar', 'baz'));
```

or

```
class Foo {

    public function __construct($bar, $baz) {
        ...
    }

}

$obj = new Foo('bar', 'baz');
```

Anything else is quite insane. If your object constructor is so complicated, you probably need to simplify it.

Comment: The class constructor isn't that complicated, it just takes the objects and external variables that the functions of the class need and stores them for use, then generates the HTML ready for output on command. ReflectionClass does seem to be the way to go, but I don't really understand it. Can you expand your answer please?

Comment: What else do you want to know? Read the manual? http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php

Comment: I think what @Styphon is trying to do is somehow generate the *textual* php code he would normally use to instantiate a given class and run that code at the same time...

Comment: @deceze I was just struggling to get my head around it, an example. such as Ben's answer, would have been ideal. I got there in the end though, thank you.